# How to do Jenkins Merge Builder configuaration for gitlab repositories

Tags: jenkins

I want to configure two git lab repository for merging branch to master please help me how to configure.

If I have gitlab.com and synapse.gitlab.com then if I want run merge builder for both repo means how could I do in Jenkins configuration.

Please help me